# Google Form Responses deleting Formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet receiving responses from a Google Form, and I am trying to set up some formulas that dynamically engage with new entries as they come in. However, whether I put the formulas on the same sheet where the data populates in a different column, or if I set up a new sheet to reference the other sheet, each time new data comes in, it deletes everything on that same row.

To be clear, I have formulas set up to use the rows directly below the last line of data, and then when a new entry populates, it deletes everything in that row. I've also tried using a different sheet, copying the data over, and it still deletes all the data on the same row on another sheet as well.

Is there a way to dynamically move the Form Responses data as it comes in to a place where it won't be manipulating other cells?

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem with that. Leave the answers in their own columns and create an array formula in subsequent columns. Example:

[image]